# Heroku is ignoring bundle configuration

Tags: heroku, rubygems, bundler, taglib-ruby

I'm trying to install the gem 'taglib-ruby' on Heroku. This gem compiles as a native extension which requires a system dependency called taglib, so after compiling and uploading it through heroku vulcan, I achieved to compile the gem via command line on heroku bash:

```
bundle exec gem install taglib-ruby -- --with-opt-dir=/app/vendor/taglib
```

And in order to this parameter would be used by **bundler** later, I added it as a bundler configuration through the command:

```
bundle config build.taglib-ruby '--with-opt-dir=/app/vendor/taglib'
```

I've already verified this config was applied, inspecting the file /.bundle/config and looking for the line BUNDLE_BUILD__TAGLIB-RUBY.

However after pushing out my project to heroku and while it is executing the *bundle install* command, **heroku complains that the above gem (taglib-ruby) cannot be installed due the taglib library isn't present**, although it's what I was trying to solve with the option *'--with-opt-dir=/app/vendor/taglib'* mentioned above.

**So it appears that Heroku is ignoring the bundler configuration.**

What could be happening? Do you know another way the achieve the same intention (install a gem with custom build options) on Heroku?

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the mkmf.log file?

Comment: Heroku vulcan and vendoring binaries like so requires your own buildpack, right? Are you doing that?

Comment: Different gem, but same basic issue: I need to pass specific flags to bundler to get it to work on my local system, like so `bundle config build.RedCloth --with-cflags=-w`. Works great locally, but then when I push to Heroku, the bundle there fails because it doesn't have the build flags. Frustrating. Still looking for a solution.